# Is there a way to synchronise my local hard-disks folders to s3

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization

I am trying to sync my local hard-disks folders to the s3 bucket, the thing is that the local folders are separated to few drivers like C:\, D:\ and so on...

For example the files in S3 Bucket includes 'RD1' to 'RD80' directories and in the local files C:\ holds 'RD1' to 'RD12', 'D:\' contain 'RD12' to 'RD20' and so on...

There is anyway to use aws cli sync command to accomplish my needs?

I wrote python script that would compere the two backups but i do prefer to use sync command and permanently control the synchronization.

Thanks alot,
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI [`aws s3 sync` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) will synchronize files from one location to another location, including subdirectories.

If you wish to synchronize multiple directories to different locations, then you will need to run the `sync` command multiple times.

Also, please note that the `sync` command is one-way, either from your local computer to S3 or from S3 to the local computer (or S3 to S3). If you want to sync in 'both directions', then you would need to execute the `sync` command both ways. This is especially important for handling deleted files, which are only deleted in the destination location if you use the `--delete` option.